# VS Code Error vs Visual Studio 2019 Error

Tags: visual-studio-code, visual-c++, error-handling, visual-studio-2019

I Used VS code to write some code but the compiler is working only in the terminal. So I set up Visual Studio 2019 For C++ but get an error that I didn't get in VS Code. (I know the solution to the error):

> The uninitialized local variable 'name' used

and the solution is Just adding these `{}` brackets to the variable.

Why is This Happening in Visual Studio 2019 and not in VS Code?

Note: I Installed "MinGW" for VS Code and desktop development with C++ for Visual Studio 2019.

Additional: I Want Visual Studio 2019 to Show unused scopes (`#Include` things) and help me to clean code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your [exception settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2022) in Visual Studio (Ctrl + Alt + E) and/or your [Warning Level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-option-warning-level?view=msvc-170) on the Project file (right click on project in solution explorer, click Properties, C/C++ > General > Warning Level).

The warning/exception controls in Visual Studio are rather detailed.

The "warning that is now an error" issue related to *The uninitialized local variable 'name' used* simply comes down to the out-of-the-box settings in Visual Studio. You can change them if you'd like. Technically, your code will compile under every C++ compiler I'm aware of, but has a greater likelihood of crashing.

As for whether it should be a warning or an error, that is more opinion than fact. My *opinion* is that it should be an error, because such situations can lead to very sneaky program crashes, but there is no hard-and-fast rule.